# Upload endpoint certificate does not solve ssl issue

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am testing endpoint and I get "connection error" to the endpoint.
I added a certificate using [this wso2 tutorial](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/4.1.0/design/endpoints/certificates/)
but it still not working.
wso2 is deployed using helm chart on openshift.
[link to helm chart](https://github.com/wso2/kubernetes-apim/tree/master/advanced/am-pattern-4)

in pod cp-1 I get the following error:

```
ERROR - GlobalThrowableMapper Error while persisting API
ERROR - ApisApiServiceImpl Error occurred while sending the HEAD request to the given endpoint url:
javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverified Exception: peer not authenticated
```

in deployment.toml in cp only the keystore.tls is configured:

```
    [keystore.tls]
    file_name =  "wso2carbon.jks"
    type =  "JKS"
    password =  "wso2carbon"
    alias =  "wso2carbon"
    key_password =  "wso2carbon"

    #[keystore.primary]
    #file_name =  "wso2carbon.jks"
    #type =  "JKS"
    #password =  "wso2carbon"
    #alias =  "wso2carbon"
    #key_password =  "wso2carbon"

    #[keystore.internal]
    #file_name =  "wso2carbon.jks"
    #type =  "JKS"
    #password =  "wso2carbon"
    #alias =  "wso2carbon"
    #key_password =  "wso2carbon"
```

in axis2.xml the location of the key stores are configured this way:

```
<Location>repository/resources/security/wso2carbon.jks<Location>
<Location>repository/resources/security/client-truststore.jks<Location>
```

I use a volume mount to replace the default keystore and truststore following this:
[text](https://github.com/wso2/container-guide/blob/master/deploy/Managing_Keystores_And_Truststores.md)

In http it does work. I imported the endpoint certificate following this:
https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/4.1.0/design/endpoints/certificates/

After I upload a new endpoint certificate in publisher, I checked all of the client-truststore.jks occurrences in all pods to see if the certificate uploaded successfully. only the default client-truststore.jks in cp-1, (that is in the default location, <WSO2_PRODUCT_HOME>/repository/resources/security and not in the custom one in - /home/wso2carbon/wso2-artifact-volume/repository/resources/security). It also did not update in any other pod (traffic-manager1/2, gateway1/2 or cp2) and not in the secret value.

What did I miss?